# Can this be considered a pure function (functional programming)?

Tags: functional-programming, purely-functional, paradigms

I've been reading about functional programming and its concepts. It's clear to me that when working in big projects you always need to mix (at some adequate level) multiple paradigms such as OO and functional. In theory, concepts such as function purity are too strict such as

> The function always evaluates the same result value given the same argument value(s). The function result value cannot depend on any hidden information or state that may change while program execution proceeds or between different executions of the program, nor can it depend on any external input from I/O devices. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)

That said, is this (or can be considered) code a pure function?

```
const externalVar = 10;

function timesTen(value) {
    return externalVar * value;
}
```

I'm asking this because, in this case, the `timesTen` function will **always** return the same value for an input, and anyone can change the value of `externalVar` as this is a constant. However, this code breaks the rule of accessing external function's scope.

Comment: Please note that pure functions often have dependencies to other functions too, and as long as these other functions are pure, the dependent functions are also considered pure. I can't see how your example differs from that. So yes, `timesTen` is a pure function. You have no guarantee for referential transparency in Javascript though. Hence it would probably be more appropriate to say that you can be confident that your function is pure.

Comment: I totally agree with you @ftor! And as for the language, please, just ignore that. My question is concerned with the concepts, not actually what concepts I can achieve with some specific language.

Comment: @thiagoh of course a function remains pure if all of its dependencies are pure - this is the essence of what ftor is saying, and I agree with him 100%.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It is guaranteed to be pure.

The reason is that it only depends on bound and immutable free variables.

> However, this code breaks the rule of accessing external function's
>   scope.

There is nothing in your quote that says you cannot access free variables. It says external input as reading from a file, network, etc not a free variable from a previous scope.

Even Haskell use global function names like `foldr` and it is a free variable in every function it is used and of course the result is pure.

Remember that functions by name is just variables. `parseInt` is a variable that points to a function so it would have been hard to make anything at all if every function you should use in another function be passed as parameter.

If you redefine `parseInt` to something that is not pure or during the duration of your program so that it works differently then no function calling it would be pure.

Function composition and partial evaluation work because they supply free variables. Its an essential method of abstraction in functional programming. eg.

```js
function compose(f2, f1) {
  return (...args) => f2(f1(...args));
}

function makeAdder(initialValue) {
  return v => v + initialValue;
}

const add11 = compose(makeAdder(10), makeAdder(1));
add11(5); // ==> 16
```

This is pure. The closure variable / free variable `f1`, `f2`, `initialValue` never changes for the created functions. `add11` is a pure function.

Now look at `compose` again. It looks pure but it can be tainted. If not both functions passed to it were pure the result isn't either.

## OO can be purely functional too!

They can easily be combined by not mutating the objects you create.

```js
class FunctionalNumber {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  add(fn) {
    return new FunctionalNumber(this.value + fn.value);
  }
  sub(fn) {
    return new FunctionalNumber(this.value - fn.value);
  }        
}
```

This class is purely functional.

In fact you can think of a method call like `obj.someMethod(arg1, arg2)` as a function call with `obj` as first argument `someFunction(obj, arg1, arg2)`. It's only syntactic differences and if `someFunction` mutated `obj` you would have said it was not pure. This is how it is with `someMethod` and `obj` too.

You can make classes that work on large data structures that are functional, which means you never have to copy it before changing when doing a backtracking puzzle solver. A simple example is the pair in Haskell and Lisp. Here is one way to make it in JavaScript:

```js
class Cons {
  constructor(car, cdr) {
    this.car = car;
    this.cdr = cdr;
  }
}

const lst = new Cons(1, new Cons(2, new Cons(3, null)));
const lst0 = new Cons(0, lst);
```

`lst0` is `lst` but with a new element in front. `lst0` reuses everything in `lst`. Everything from lists to binary trees can be made with this and you can make many sequential data structures with immutable binary trees. It's been around since the 50s.

Comment: "If you redefine parseInt to something that is not pure or during the duration of your program so that it works differently then no function calling it would be pure." that's exactly the way I think! I put this question here after much discussion with friends. They were blinded by the literal words that said that a pure function cannot access anything from outside. Accepted this as the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I understand your opinion and totally agree with @Sylwester, but there's a point that is worth mention: with reflection external constant values can be modified and break the pureness of your function. We know that everything in IT can be hacked and we should not considere this over the concepts, but in practice we should have this clear in mind, that in this way functional pureness is unsound.